# Blender UV mapping error

Tags: texturing, uv

I have an error with UV mapping where it looks fine until I actually render it or throw it into a program that renders it. I'm not sure what the issue is because I hardly ever use blender.

What it should look like: (the mapped image is for testing)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mNHfyRP.png]

What it actually renders like:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/FIDjkAB.png]

Answer (score 8):

UVs will always show well in the *3d view*, they only come out wrong when rendered as the textures more than likely weren't configured properly.

[image]
[image]

It looks like your mapping is set to *Generated* or something else possibly. You can fix this by going to the texture tab and under *Mapping*, select *UV* from the *Coordinates* list.

[image]

To be safe, you can also create a uvmap or use the auto-generated one under *UV Maps* in the *Object Data* panel and select it in the texture tab under *Mapping* once you have changed to those coordinates.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This was very confusing because textures were showing fine in editor, but weren't coming up when rendering.