# How is this blendfile hiding textures?

Tags: texturing, blend-files

I saw [this tutorial on Blender Nation](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/07/15/how-to-make-3d-minecraft-animations-with-blender/) that deal with creating Minecraft animations in Blender.  After following several links, I finally came up with the file and downloaded it.

I could edit the images that were used to texture the models.  However, when I wanted to disable anti-aliasing/sampling, I discovered that the textures are not linked to their objects in the usual way (i.e., through the Textures tab in the Properties panel).  In fact, I have not been able to find *any* link between the textures and the objects that they adorn.

What is going on here?  Am I just missing something blindingly obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this is that *none* were created, the author simply unwrapped the models and changed the view to *Textured*.

Here is a quick example using the texture I unpacked from the file. As you can see, the cube doesn't even have a material. This is perfectly legit in Blender but really bad practice as it pertains to asset management etc.

[image]

Since the objects are already unwrapped, to fix it, just create a texture and change *Coordinates* under *Mapping* to *UV*. For a bit more information on correct UV mapping, see [Blender UV mapping error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/blender-uv-mapping-error)

Comment: It is also worth noting that this won't render by default. It will only show in the _3d view_. It renders because _Face Textures_ is ticked under the material options.

Comment: Thanks for your comment iKlsR, it helped me in some simmilar project and spared me a lot of time.