# How to show textures in the 3D View editor?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I have added some textures to objects in blender but the textures don't show up until I render the file. it can be difficult to know what the objects look like without rendering it. is there a way to have textures show in the editor even if they are at a lower res?

In editor:

[image]

Rendered:

[image]

Comment: blender crashed when I tried to use the material viewport

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Switch to *Material* viewport shading by clicking the icon in the top right of the 3D view:

[image: Textured Suzanne with material shading enabled]

If you have an image texture, you can also display textures in solid shading mode by switching to "texture" in the shading mode options drop down:

[image]

---

## Blender 2.5x - 2.7x:

#### Blender internal:

Try setting the [viewport shading](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options#View_Shading) to *Texture* (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>):

[image]

Note that this only works when the object's UV map has the appropriate texture displayed in the UV/image editor: (see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/how-is-this-blendfile-hiding-textures) for more information)

[image]

To display the textures used in the material of the object regardless of the texture (or lack of texture) displayed in the *UV image editor*, enable *GLSL* in *3D view > Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Shading* and set the viewport shading to *Texture*:

[image]

#### Cycles:

You need a material to display textures in the viewport in cycles.

Set the viewport shading to *Texture* or *Material*.

*Texture* displays the texture of the last selected image texture node:

[image]

*Material* tries to approximate the result of the shader nodes, so if you have two combined textures:

[image]

Comment: I can't find that last option could you post a larger screenshot. also I am using blender 2.66a if it matters

Comment: @qwertyk31 In blender 2.66a it's under the *Display* panel *IIRC*. (Assuming you mean *GLSL*)

Comment: yea I did mean GLSL but I will just update blender I don't know why the Ubuntu software center one is out of date

Comment: I have enabled GLSL but still no textures.

Comment: Got it working but is there a way to lower the res of the textures because it lags blender way to much.

Comment: @qwertyk31 AFAIK, No. You could manually create lower resolution versions of the textures.

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm having real trouble in making this work in Cycles. I think I activated all the options you've mentioned.... Is anyone aware of known issues to make the textures work in realtime in the viewport? i can only see them in "rendered" shading mode. please help!

Comment: @invicente Do you got it working yet? Everything looks so outdated. I also need to add a `Geometry node` and connect `Position` to `Vector` in the `Image Texture` node to make it show up in rendered but I still dont have anything in Texture for the viewport shading.

Comment: How do I make it fully lit? Everything looks very dark when I set "Texture" view mode.

Comment: @AaronFranke See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10943/599

Comment: I can't even find the menu where I'm supposed to enable 3D view.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica I've updated my answer for 2.8x, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I'm using 2.93.6, and my GUI looks far different. I cannot find some of the settings mentioned in the answer. If anyone knows of a similar explanation for that version, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @EJMak The first part of the answer should be up to date, which setting are  you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

The object with the texture needs to have its *Maximum Draw Type* set to *Textured*. This setting is in Properties Editor > Object settings then the *Display* section. This applies to Cycles and Blender Internal.

Comment: That is the default and seem not to work.