# Is there a textured but unlit (full bright) viewport mode?

Tags: 3d-view, light

I'm trying to display models that have shading drawn or baked directly on the textures, but I can't figure out how to disable Blender's default scene lighting. If there are no lights in the scene, everything is black, but I want to see the textured objects fully bright. How do I disable the lighting?

NOTE: Just before posting this, I found the "Shadeless" material property, which does more or less what I want. However, is there a way to globally toggle the default lighting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can enable *Shadeless* in *3D view > Properties (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Shading* while in textured view:

[image]

If you are in BI, this only works if using *Multitexture shading*:

[image]

If you are using GLSL in BI or material shading in Cycles, you'll have to use shadeless in the material settings for BI and a emission shader for cycles.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The reason I didn't spot the Shadeless option there is that Multitexture has always failed to render textures on any PC I have tried it on, and I always have to end up using GLSL. Maybe I should ask about that in my next question!

Comment: @MrFlamey I doubt it's a hardware issue (usually GLSL shading is the one with problems..), but you never know. Here's a related post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5283/599.