# How to disable scene shading and view Vertex Colors only?

Tags: 3d-view, vertex-colors

I'm working with an older model from another program (3DS Max) meant to be rendered in an engine running on older hardware with no dynamic lighting (Faked with shaders and vertex coloring)

The model was exported from Max as a DAE and imported into Blender. Upon importing, I found that it has this sort of automated shading going on based on which angle you view the model from, which really interferes when I'm trying to paint vertex colors.

Max has a 'flat' shading option which disables all scene lighting/shading and leaves vertex colors and textures only. Is there anyway to do this in Blender?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10942/599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, enable *Shadeless* in *3D view > Tool Shelf (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Shading* while in textured view (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>):

[image]