# texture not seem to show up in texture shading mode

Tags: texturing

I[image] added image texture to a material, uv unwrapped it and choose texture shading mode but it still not show up a texture in a viewport. Any thoughts on why is it happening?

Comment: the surface of the chest needs to be shown textured.By the way Im using old computer, - can it be a hardware problem?

Comment: You can read about the [texture draw type](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/texture_editing.html#d-viewport-draw-types) in the 3D viewport [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-editor). It may be easier to check whether it's hardware problem by inspecting your file (or part of it, downloaded [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)). If it works fine, then this will be the answer

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=525" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/525/) here's the blend file

Comment: If anyone finds out that on his computer it works fine, please, write a couple lines here

Comment: @Mr Zak also it gets black in material shading mode

Comment: Your setup [works fine](https://imgur.com/MGk9gAH), so I think the problem is not in your file. Did you have such problems before? What video card do you have?