# How to see texture on the mesh in viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I can´t see the test texture placed according to the UV unwrap I made for the mesh. I preview mesh in Texture shading mode. These are screenshots in Edit mode showing unwrapped mesh:

[image: screenshot 1 of mesh]

[image: screenshot 2 of the mesh]

Comment: To preview texture on the mesh in Cycles add material for the mesh, in setup of that material add Image node with that image selected in its dropdown list. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor

Comment: now I understand, in the script I followed the uv would apply automatically, ty for the response