# Why dont I see my texture on the object?

Tags: texturing

I wanted to apply texture on some house following an tutorial, I'm sure I did all what was needed but still don't see the texture.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: did you add a material that uses the texture and it's uv to your house model ?a screenshot of your house material nodes would help.

Comment: Can you include your .blend file?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor

Answer (score 1):

In cycles you to create materials using shaders.

[image]

Select the faces you want to use those materials, and assign the material to them with the assign button.

[image]

The image needs to be used as a texture by the shader using the mapping you've set up on the Texture coordinates.

[image]