# Color not showing up on object?

Tags: color

I'm new to blender, and I'm working on a project. I texture painted my character, and it shows up fine, but once I switch to object mode, it disappears. 
[image: cobra in texture/material mode]

I also need to import this character into JME, so if anyone could help me with that too, that'd be fantastic. 
Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to save the texture painting as an image and add that image to your material(s).

Comment: I already did that; it still doesn't appear in object mode.

Comment: If you'd like to preview your painted texture in 3D Viewport, then see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor

Comment: How would I make my painted texture a permanent, visible part of the object (esp. when I import files)?

Comment: Any number of things could have caused the problem. Could you upload your file (with images packed)?