# Texture is not displayed on the meshes. How to display?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm newbie to Blender.

Please see the following screenshot.

[image]

I've unwrapped the UVs for the mesh, generated a test image, set the 3D view display mode to Texture. But the texture does not show on the mesh.

In fact, for some time the texture was displayed on the meshes. But one day I tried to unwrap a remaining mesh, the texture was not displayed on that mesh. I tried a few menus, but failed.

Then I removed the test image by Shift-clicking 'X' button on the UV image name widget, saving the file, and reloading. Then... all meshs lost the texture.

It seems that the texture link of the UV map is lost. How can I recover it? And, how can I apply texture to the remaining meshes that refuse to display the texture even after the UV unwrapping?

Comment: How does your material setup look like?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view. The mesh might even not have UV map (Blender Internal only), but you need to select all its faces in Edit mode and open desired image. Shift-clicking X button - that's how it works.

Comment: Is the texutre assigned to the material?

Comment: @MrZak Thanks! It was very simple. Select all its faces in Edit mode, and open a desired image or just open the image list on the lower left of the UV editing window, and select an image. If you post this as an answer, I'll choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show texture on the mesh in Blender Internal it's enough to open / create an image texture in UV / Image Editor (or choose already existing one from the list of the images in the .blend file) while all faces of the mesh are selected in Edit mode.
The mesh even doesn't need to be UV unwrapped (although it isn't a good solution as there isn't any control of the image assignment).

[image: screenshot of showing texture in 3D viewport]

Note though that it's necessary to unwrap the mesh in order to control appearence of the texture on it and open desired image in UV / Image Editor with all faces selected.

The last step in order to show assigned image in the 3D Viewport is either to enable [Texture Shading](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/display/shading.html#shading-modes) (note - lighting setup will be taken into account) or enable *Textured Solid* (note - [assigned face textures will be displayed](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/display/shading.html#shading-panel)) in the *Properties* shelf > *Shading* rollout.

See more on previewing textures in 3D Viewport -[How to show textures in the 3D View editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor).