# Why is blender not displaying texture controls

Tags: texturing, interface

[image: a busy cat]
[image: two muppets]

It will display texture controls for the objects named gatehouse base L and gatehouse base R only

Comment: Solid shading mode will not display textures, try texture, material or render mode.

Comment: hmmm it also now doing the same thing for the "materials" properties panel for some objects

Comment: after only making different objects visible and invisible (clicking around on the eye icons) the materials and texture controls are now visible for all objects. I am truly lost on this one.

Comment: it happened again! added a second material. couldn't see the texture controls when that new material was selected but could for the first. Then I walked a way and when I came back I could see texture controls. any ideas out there?

Comment: Can you show what do you mean by "texture controls" ? Previewing textures on the model depends on render engine. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor

Comment: figured it out. all I had to do was scroll up on the textures panel. *~*WhOOpS*~*