# Blender 2.8 Viewport Texture button

Tags: 3d-view

Hi all i am following a tutorial "Creating Landscapes Blender 2.8" and get to the point where he switches from Rendered view to Texture. My viewport does not show a Texture display Button. Any ideas as can't find and info in preferences or online#

Thanks in advance
[image: My Viewport]

I seem to have Loodev and they have Texture
[image: Waywards Viewport]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to do something like this for the texture to show up in viewport.

[image]

Comment: I can see how that will show the texture that has been drawn however on there 3d view second button alng it is a texture one and mine (and by the looks of it yours it is the "LookDev" button wondering how you manage these buttons as can't find it in preferences. And i have the latest version downloaded yesterday. possible the removed it and replacedit with LookDev and the tutorial i was following was made on a previous 2.8 build

Comment: apologies for spelling fat finger syndrome and dodgy keyboard

Comment: LookDev has replaced the texture view a while ago.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stz9pL_pq9I) that show this workflow.