# Strange blue color in Solid mode

Tags: modeling, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

Recently, encountered a problem with this strange blue color in solid mode. It did not harm me until I exported this model, and this blue color combines with any material I add. For example, skin + blue = purple skin. It looks like a normal map, but I don’t know how to remove it from the mesh.

Any ideas? I'm new to Blender.

[image: blue color in solid mode]

[image]

Comment: You are using the Blender internal renderer, can you switch to Cycles? (drop down at the top of the Blender window) Internal is being depreciated and you will get more support using Cycles.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the .blend file to take a look?

Comment: Just in case you want to upload the file, use this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's still possible to get expected behviour from Blender Internal even that it's to be dropped soon. There is mesh object with normal map texture shown on the screenshot, the fact that GLSL and Textured Solid are enabled means that the current texture is to be shown regardless currently selected texture in UV editor, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5284/1245. The fact that this color combines with any other might probably mean texture slot with this blue texture is set to some Blend mode in texture settings other than Mix

Comment: @FranciscoArleo I added blend file.

Comment: @rob I don't use blender as a render engine, so cycles/internal should work similar for me. With cycles engine I don't see this issue in blender, but exported model still have the problem.

Comment: @MrZak make sense, but I can't find any texture assigned to this mesh. You may check attached blend file

Comment: The color seems to be in a vertex color layer: 'Col', set to renderable I can't figure out how it was supposed to be used..

Comment: @RobinBetts thanks a lot! I don't know either :)