# Object-Specific, "Material Preview" Viewport Shading?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, 3d-view, customization

One of the ways I like to incorporate references into whatever I'm modeling is by inserting an image into the 3D space I'm working in. However, in order for the Texture Image I've added to show up, I have to go to "Material Preview" Viewport Shading for the **entirety** of my scene.

I'd like to only apply "Material Preview" Viewport Shading to my reference (so the texture displays) and stay in "Solid" viewport shading for the rest of my scene/whatever it is I'm making. Here's what I'm referring to:

[image]

[image]

Is this possible? If not I can make do modelling in "Material Preview" instead of "Solid" (like I have thus far).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show textures in the 3D View editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Just set colour to texture with that little dropdown arrow :)

Comment: Yep this is it!

Comment: If that's it, please consider to accept the answer @J_D https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Yeah I was confused when he made his own answer to the question instead of just accepting mine

Comment: Sorry about that, was typing up my answer when I refreshed and saw yours

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out! Go to "Shading" (little arrow next to Viewport Shading modes like "Solid" & "Material Preview" and select "Texture" for the object's "Color"

[image]