# UV map not applying to certain faces

Tags: texturing, uv, image

As you can see, certain faces are not being textured, despite the map covering them. On the UV view there are vertexes which are unselected, but selecting them manually makes no difference - they are unselected as a result of an unmapping, and I suspect the issue is linked to those vertexes, although deleting them and remaking them only makes the problem worse. Please note, the textures are not invisible, but white, so I know the normals are all fine (I checked them anyway, and they are all the correct way round). There are no doubles either. I'm genuinely stumped by this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou.

[image]

Comment: The one face which isn't working is an ngon, but I don't think that should make any difference.. Is it possible you could upload a .blend?

Comment: Sure, http://www.mediafire.com/download/ur7nq6h2j278rjo/PT99.zip I didn't link the textures since it's late and I forgot how. They're in a separate folder. Thanks.

Comment: That works, thanks. Been struggling with that for ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of the UV map is not assigned to an image. If you just select the face, you'll notice that the image in the UV/image editor disappears.
Select the face and then select the image in the UV/image editor to "assign" it. To be sure of this not happening again, you should probably do this with the entire mesh selected (<kbd>A</kbd>).

Note that with proper materials/textures setup, this won't affect the render.

---

Also see [How is this blendfile hiding textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3772/599)