# Show both material and texture at the same time

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, faces

I have an object with a certain material. I want to add an image to a group of neighboured faces so that they all represent one image (not each one has the same image, each one will display part of the image) and make this appear in the 3d view.

I tried this:

- Going into edit-mode
- select faces needed
- Unwrap
- Open UV viewer and select the image
- check the Textured Solid checkbox under shading in the 3dview properties window

The image now appears on the faces, but the material is no longer appearing.

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

This is my object with a certain material:
[image]

and this is what happens as soon as I check the Textured Solid checkbox under shading in the 3dview properties window:

[image]

But I want it to have my material (blueish in this case) and also have some faces (eye in this case) with the image.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5203/599

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I got the above result by:

1. ["Applying" the image to the eye faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14597/599)
2. Unwrapping the appropriate faces (<kbd>U</kbd>)
3. Switching to material shaded view.

Make sure there is a light source to be able to view the materials in the material shaded view.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need two separate materials. See [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/6385) for how to assign multiple materials to one object. In this case you will want the eyes to be one material, with the texture, and the body to be a separate material with the blue.

Your issue is caused by the texture overwriting the flat diffuse. Since only the eye is UV mapped, it is the only thing that shows up textured in texture view. Without using nodes or anything too complicated the only solution is two separate materials, one for texture and one for diffuse.

One material is plain diffuse;

[image]

One material is plain texture;

[image]

Combine and assign to faces in edit mode;

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already know how to set different materials to different parts of the object. So could you please provide your answers with steps and screenshots to follow? as I followed it but I still can't get both material and texture be visible at the same time in the 3d view

Comment: @Tak step by step instructions are found on the other question. i am updating the answer with screenshots.