# Disappearing textures, how do I solve it?

Tags: rendering, mesh, image

The color I gave to my Headset 
wich I used on my rig, colored white after rendering the image, how do I solve this??? 
(I unwrapped the picture, so that is not the problem)

[image: In 3D view:]

[image: In rendered version:]

Comment: He's asking about the headset- where did the texture go?

Comment: Indeed, forgot to mention that, excuses me.

Comment: Did you create a material texture? See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3772/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6534/599

Comment: I kindof get what you mean, but is there any way you can import colors from a picture into a material?