# My render animation has no color?

Tags: rendering, animation

Ill been using blender since a month ago thanks to tutorials and the blender guide and now that I render my animation has no color, My mesh already has texture but the texture doesnt appear in my .avi extension/output its only grey or black and white, does anyone know?
-Edward S.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Blender render (not Cycles) ? Do you have lights in your scene ?

Comment: Yes blender render and I do have lights on my scene:(

Comment: Could you show some screen captures or upload your blend file here ? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1670" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1670/

Comment: There is something strange with the lamps : I cannot see or select them (first time I encounter that...). Which Blender version are you using ?

Comment: Blender 2.77 yeah maybe I exceed the light or well I really dont know

Comment: For now, the only thing I can say is that if I add a lamp, I see your character again when rendering.

Comment: So should I add more light to my scene? I am really thank for all your help

Comment: I don't know what happened. If I was you, I delete the lamps and recreate them again (you can delete them using the outliner)

Comment: I did and now the mesh looks white but the texture colors dont. I want to show you a screenshot but how do I upload it?

Comment: There I put a screenshot my question is, does that modify or affects my render animation in any way ?

Comment: In the file I have downloaded your meshes have no materials assigned.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/render-not-showing-uv-texture. Your file indeed doesn't have any materials, only textures assigned to meshes in Edit mode. While it's visible in preview, it won't be rendered by default (using non-default isn't good practice)..

Comment: Really really thanks Lemon and Mr zak that would help. Thank you:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is this blendfile hiding textures?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/how-is-this-blendfile-hiding-textures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any materials assigned to the objects; thus no textures will be rendered. You can preview textures in 3D Viewport because in Blender Internal it isn't required to have material in order to preview texture on the model; it is enough to select faces in Edit mode and open desired image in UV/Image Editor (no need even to unwrap it and assign texture to UV map):

[image: screenshot no materials but texture visible]

You still have possibility to render these textures by enabling *Face Textures* in properties, however you will need to create material for that:

[image: screenshot no textures on object but image is renderable]

Do keep in mind that this is not a good practice and should be avoided; create textures, assigned to the material and link them to images instead.

Comment: Mr Zak thanks a lot I finally got it, thanks for the support and help.