# materials on cylinder have changed from workspace to render

Tags: modeling, animation, materials, edit-mode

I'm working on a cylinder with 8 sections and when I have worked on other shapes before my materials have rendered fine, but with the cylinder as I click render my materials have disappeared or one has been pasted over each section shape.

There might just be a simple solution I'm missing, but I need help fast! much appreciated if anyone can thanks!

examples of what I mean:

Editing Stage:

[image]

Rendered Image:

[image]

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: could you upload the blend file?

Comment: The viewport is most likely using the UV coords for displaying the texture. While rendering uses the material settings, which can be a different texture layout. Check your texture mapping setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender UV mapping error](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/blender-uv-mapping-error).

Comment: I don't know how to get my file on here, what do I need to change to get the viewpoint and render to display the same thing?

Comment: @Elimyxlov you can upload via [pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) then share the link here.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27306 you won't see my images though will that be a problem?

Comment: I tried creating seams just now but that hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I hadn't realised I needed to click on assign twice as I had only done it once and wasn't sure why it hadn't worked.

So it did end up being something simple that I'd missed