# Why does my scene preview look so different than the render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

In my 3d scene view, with display mode set to "textured", my texture looks fine. But when I render it the texture stretches all over the place. All my settings are at default, just a single sun object for lighting.

[image: Scene view]
[image: Rendered]

Comment: Make sure the mapping is set to UV in the texture settings

Comment: @user5530 If gandalf3's advice helped you, please accepted his answer, be click on the check mark.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1750/599

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you have UV mapping selected in *Properties > Textures > Mapping > Coordinates*:

[image]

If you only have one UV map it's not necessary to select it in the *Map* drop down, but you can if you want.