# rendering textures

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I've made a low poly wolf, just to learn how to unwrap objects and make a easy texture, but when i wanted to render the final image blender didn'render the texture and rendered just the basic gray material. What do I have to do if I want my texture rendered?

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14849/599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Blender Render ( Internal) , Make sure you have set a texture / Assigned a material to your wolf . To do this :

1. Select the walk , Go into edit mode and select the material Tab in the properties panel [*If you have not got any materials in the tab , Click "New"]*

[image]

2.Make sure everything is selected ( Press A until everything is highlighted ) , and press "Assign"

3. Select the Texture tab ( It is a checkered image next to the materials tab )

And click on one of the empty slots , And select the following :

[image]

4. Now set the Co - Ordinates , As shown :

[image]

5. Try and render the image now . Make sure you have Ambient Occlusion on , Or make sure you have lights in the scene so the wolf is visible.