# Textures rendering in grey

Tags: rendering, mesh

I got to the point on my first image (.obj) on Blender where I'm ready to render.
However while the correct colours are showing in the 3D window, it's only rendering in grey. I've been through a few forums but can't seem to find anything that fixes the issue.

[image: Render - Before]

[image: Render - After]

Comment: Show a screenshot of material you are using on that scene. I have a feeling it might not have texture applied anywhere on the material.

Comment: Most likely it's the Material override on the Render Layer. This allows you to specify a material to use for everything within that render layer. Check the Render Layer properties Material setting and ensure it is unset. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50317/29586

Comment: Thanks Rich, I've tried following that suggestion but unfortunately it hasn't done the trick.

Comment: Make sure the Output is not set to BW, next to the output file format in the Render tab. Just seen you are using Blender internal, not sure where that setting is outside of Cycles.

Comment: Try rendering in cycles.If not working please post your blender file.

Comment: Changing to another render engine will just break all materials. Blender render can render in color generally.

Comment: Blender file, hopefully the link works:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FaCnFxz1n_hDOYMw5FoboEweHum8yiDr

Comment: To expand on the first comment, you need to create textures for rendering. When you unwrap or texture paint, blender keeps that texture information and uses it in the viewport but it is not used in the render. See the answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21522/935).