# How to apply and export baked cycles textures.

Tags: texturing, uv, export, texture-baking, collada

so I have successfully baked a texture onto my object in cycles. Is this new image texture already applied as a texture? When exporting, for example, with collada, it's recommended to export from the blender render. I tried to switch over to the blender render and make a new texture using the image texture baked with cycles, but the uv's didn't match. What is the quickest and best way to export a mesh with the new baked texture.

Comment: BI and cycles use the same uv data. Do you maybe have a mapping node that scales the uv's in cycles? Are you mapping to uv in BI and not generated?

Comment: I'll have a look at the .blend file if you like.  You can post them using PasteAll.org.  Once you upload it there, you can paste the link here.

Comment: There's a good chance this answers your question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/blender-uv-mapping-error